# Index Error after for loop has already completed one loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to plot the last 30 days of sst data using a for loop.  My code will run through the first loop fine but then give this error on the second:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sstt.py", line 20, in <module>
    Temp = Temp[i,:,:]
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

It doesn't matter what indice I start on, the second loop always gives this error. If I start on -29, then -28 fails. If I start on -28, -27 fails, etc.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import math as m
import urllib2
from pydap.client import open_url
from pydap.proxy import ArrayProxy

data_url_mean = 'http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/thredds/dodsC/Datasets/noaa.oisst.v2.highres/sst.day.mean.2015.v2.nc'

dataset1 = open_url(data_url_mean)

# Daily Mean

Temp = dataset1['sst']

timestep = [-29,-28,-27,-26,-25,-24,-23,-22,-21,-20,-19,-18,-17,-16,-15,-14,-13,-12,-11,-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1]

for i in timestep:

    # Daily Mean
    Temp = Temp[i,:,:]
    Temp = Temp.array[:]
    Temp = Temp * (9./5.) + 32. 
    Temp = Temp.squeeze()
    print i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning all of your values to the same variable. After the first pass of the loop, Temp is no longer equal to the dataset, and the attempt to perform the operation expecting it to be the dataset fails.

You need to come up with some new names for the variables that you assign values to.